# SQL Get a list of categories but exclude the categories that have no items?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a **categories** table and an **items** table. I have about 20 categories. In the items table there are items from 10 of those categories. I want to select all the categories that have items in the items table. I want to exclude all the categories that have no items.

The Items table has a categoryID field that matches the ID field of the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from categories c inner join items i on i.categoryID = c.id;
```

OR

```
select * from categories c where c.id in (select i.categoryID from items i);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from categories c inner join Items I on 
 I.categoryid=c.id
```